# How to checkout ours/theirs on a file in magit?

Tags: magit

Let's say I have a merge conflict. I see a conflicted file like this:

```
Unstaged changes:
    Unmerged   Foo/bar/wibble/plop/elbow.txt
```

I can hit tab here to open the changes and maybe jump to a point inside the file to fix by hand, but if it's a big file with lots of conflicts that can be time consuming.

How can I ask git, through magit, to checkout the ours or theirs version of the file, to resolve the conflict? I can copy the path, then use `Shift-:` to enter a custom git command, but it seems like there must be a keyboard shortcut for this. I can't see anything obvious in the magit menu or the `?` pop-up.

Comment: While this does not directly answer your question, but it could be useful. Move point on the conflict file in `magit-status` and press `e` to start 3-way merging with `ediff`. Another alternative is that in a conflict buffer, you can turn on `smerge-mode` for conflict highlighting and perform interactive merging right in your buffer (not ediff). The prefix key binding for `smerge-mode` related commands is `C-c ^`; you can press `C-c ^ C-h` to view all key bindings.

Comment: I don't find "ours" or "theirs" in the doc either. http://magit.github.io/master/magit.html#Pushing-and-Pulling

Comment: Looks like a good question to open a feature request ?

Comment: good idea @Ehvince, done: https://github.com/magit/magit/issues/1643

Comment: Great ! I'll follow the thread too.

Comment: Oooh: in the Next version of magit you can `k` on a confict and choose which version to keep. Sounds perfect! https://github.com/magit/magit/issues/1643

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I'm not sure when this feature was added, but it does this perfectly:

1. Merge one branch into another and encounter a conflict
2. In the Magit buffer, there will be sections for `Merging master`, and `Unstaged changes`, `Staged changes`. The conflicted file is in `Unstaged changes`
3. On the line with the conflicted file, hit `k` to discard the changes (i.e., the conflicted changes)
4. In the minibuffer, you will see the answer:

`For <conflicted file> checkout: [o]ur stage, [t]heir stage, [c]onflict, or [C-g] to abort`

Answer (score 7):

There are several solution:

- use smerge-ediff. In the file with the conflict, you run `M-x smerge-ediff`. It will put you in the ediff resolve mode, with four open buffer: yours, theirs, merge, and the command buffer. In the command buffer, you use `n` and `p` to go to next or previous hunk, "a" or "b" to accept change from the first or second buffer, or you can go to the merge buffer, and edit it to your liking.
- use ediff from magit, with `e` on the stable version of magit, or `M-e` or `M-m` (`magit-ediff-resolve`) in the next branch of magit, and then you will find yourself mostly like in the first case
- there is also smerge-mode, `C-c ^ n` and `C-c ^ p` will help you go from an hunk to the previous or next one, you can then edit them, or use `C-c ^ o` to keep the 'other' version, `C-c ^ m` to keep the 'mine' version, `C-c ^ b` to keep the old version and `C-c ^ a` to keep them all.
- you can use magit-find-file to open a file as it was in some commit.

Comment: I hadn't seen that Tu Do already had most the answer I post here. Sory

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive list, but I guess the answer to "is there a concise way to get the Ours or Thiers version" is no. :(